# Run Heroku CLI Command in Heroku Scheduler

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have deployed .NET console as a container in Heroku. I want to run this console app daily so I need to use Heroku Scheduler. I can run my application using Heroku CLI `heroku run bash --type=worker --app  serene-mountain-60523`. But when the same command is added in the Heroku Scheduler Job it does not work. I have added an authentication key in the config vars of the Heroku app.
I have tried adding a job with a command like `bash --type=worker --app  serene-mountain-60523` as well.

Comment: Surely the equivalent of that command in the scheduler is just... `bash`?

Comment: hello jonrsharpe, so i need to put bash --type=worker --app  serene-mountain-60523 or just bash?

Comment: `--type` and `--app` aren't arguments to `bash`, they're arguments to `heroku run`

Comment: I have tried using without --type and --app as well like bash serene-mountain-60523 still same issue. can you please suggest the exact command to run in the scheduler?

Comment: That's the _value_ of the app argument, again _to `heroku run`_. It's not clear what command you're even trying to schedule.

Comment: As mentioned in the task, I want to schedule the CLI command "heroku run bash --type=worker --app  serene-mountain-60523" in the scheduler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256772/discussion-between-dhanik-lal-sahni-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 0):

I could schedule a job with the command `'dotnet <app>.dll'`. the app is the name of the DLL that was put in the docker file as an entry point.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataSyncService.dll"]
```

So with this entry code, I have put `dotnet DataSyncService.dll` in Heroku Scheduler.
Ensure you have enabled at least one dyno in the resources tab. Otherwise scheduler will not work.